# TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Every time I try to run the app after add users routes it gives error something like this

```
C:\Users\adity\Desktop\thinkster\medium-api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\thinkster\medium-api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\thinkster\medium-api\app.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

> This is my file Structure

[image: file structure]

> app.js

```
const app = express();
app.use('./routes');
```

> routes/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/api', require('./api'));
module.exports = router;
```

> routes/api/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use('/', require('./users'));
module.exports = router;
```

> routes/api/users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/users', (req, res) => res.send('Hello world'));
module.exports = router;
```

I found a website called realworld.io and I am following there a way of making nodejs API and here I get stuck every time. And I can't find where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

The code `app.use('./routes');` in your `app.js` is incorrect (there is only one string parameter, which violates the `app.use()` [syntax](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)).

To define "routes" correctly, the code would look like:

```
// app.js

const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes');

app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: @LeeGoddard If `app.use` take one argument and that argument is a callback function, it is valid. However, if that one argument is a string, not a function, then it is invalid.

Comment: Yes, my apologies