# TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function in while passport authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add Passport js local strategy to my nodejs app. But every time I add this file to the app.js I get an error something like this.
The code was working fine before adding passport.js to app.js file.

I am new to using passport authentication. I have no idea where the problem is

```
C:\Users\adity\Desktop\thinkster\medium-api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\thinkster\medium-api\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adity\Desktop\thinkster\medium-api\app.js:28:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

These are my codes

> config/passport.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');
mongoose.model('User');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        username: 'user[email]',
        password: 'user[password'
    },function(email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({email: email}).then(function (user) {
        if(!user || !user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {errors: {'email of password': 'is invalid'}});
        }
        return done(null, user);
    }).catch(done);
    }
));
```

> app.js

```
 const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

const conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/medium', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});

app.use(session({secret: 'medium',
    cookie: {maxAge: 6000}, resave: false,
    saveUninitialized:false}));

app.use(passport.initialize());

if (!conn) {
    console.log('Error with database');
} else {
    console.log('Database Connected');
}
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use(require('./config/passport'));
app.use(require('./routes'));

const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're exporting anything in `config/passport.js`

Comment: Have you checked my answer to another of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921270/typeerror-app-use-requires-a-middleware-function/56922589#56922589 ? Please read the syntax of `app.use()` first.

Comment: @shaochuancs I did see your answer there but that route is now working by using only this `app.use(require('./routes'))`.

Comment: The root cause of these 2 questions are the same (they even share the same error message!) Recommend to read document on `app.use()`: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Comment: @shaochuancs  I did add `app.use(require('config.passport'))` it didn't work. Then I tried something else and it is working I wrapped the passport.use inside a function and exported it now its working do u reason for this?

Comment: Have you read the document?

Comment: @shaochuancs yes i did

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an export to your config file

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/User');
mongoose.model('User');

module.exports = passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        username: 'user[email]',
        password: 'user[password'
    },function(email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({email: email}).then(function (user) {
        if(!user || !user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {errors: {'email of password': 'is invalid'}});
        }
        return done(null, user);
    }).catch(done);
    }
));
```

I haven't tested this and am only guessing so let me know if this worked ;)

Comment: I tried this it's not working. error still remains the same.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781294/passport-js-passport-initialize-middleware-not-in-use

Comment: I think the link you have provided suggests me to add `app.use(passport.initialize());` I added them still I am getting the same error.